# Modeling using Stanford NER - Output Model file size

Tags: stanford-nlp

I trained my own model using also my own features. The size of my training dataset is 6M only. After modeling phase, The size of my model (.gz) is 420M,
Is this normal or something goes wrong???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not the training dataset which impacts the size of the model serialisation. It's what/how many features you employ. But a model of 420Mb is pretty usual.

As long as you manage to classify unseen text, no worries there.